# what is the best way to store and retrieve strings in vernacular(multiple languages) android apps?

Tags: android, string, local-storage

I am working on vernacular(multiple language support) android app where I am giving option to the user to change language. So what is the Best way to store and retrieve strings, Weather to store strings in multiple strings files according locale (But it increases app size) or to get strings from server when user changes the language or any other?  Let me know if you don't understand any thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use the Locale and create a separate file for each language with the same keys but different values according to the language. For more details, pleae have a look : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html